# Create dynamic dropdown based on data return from observable service

Tags: angular, dropdown

Is there any way to implement a dynamic list of dropdown?

The dropdown will be created based on the data returned from an observable service. When the user selects the option value from the dropdown, that value will be passed to the service, and it will send another set of data used to create a new set of dropdown options.

The data return will be something like

```
CAR_BRAND/AUDI/MODEL/R8/YEAR_OF_BUILD/2YR,
CAR_BRAND/BMW/MODEL/M3/YEAR_OF_BUILD/3YR
```

`CAR_BRAND` will be the key, `AUDI` will be the option value for the dropdown

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like this:

Add (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" to my select.

```
<div>
  <label for="options">List</label>
  <select (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]=model.options.id >
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option.id">{{option.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**.ts:**

```
options = [
    { id: 123, name: "John" },
    { id: 456, name: "Rob" },
    { id: 789, name: "Kim" },
    { id: 987, name: "Jason" },
  ];

onChange($event) {
    // your logic 
    // update the options object with the data that you get from the service
  }
```